# The Solow growth model

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, economic-growth, solow, endogenous-growth

**I wonder why at the beginning sf(k(t)) is steeper than δk(), but at some point, it starts flatter than δk(t)?**

Comment: The standard chart used to explain the Solow model plots output per worker (vertical) against capital per worker (horizontal).  It does not have a time axis.  So when you say "at the beginning", a more accurate description would be "if capital per worker is very low".

Comment: Hi! Did you know you can accept answers to [your questions](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/44577/huy-l%C3%AA-thanh?tab=questions)?

Answer (score 3):

**The answer: it is an assumption** 
Solow-models usually assume that $f$ fulfills the [Inada conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inada_conditions), points 3. and 4. of which state
$$
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{k \to 0} f'(k) = \infty \\
\lim_{k \to \infty} f'(k) = 0.
\end{equation*}
$$

**A frequent special case** 
If the production function $F(K,L)$ is of Cobb-Douglas type with constant returns to scale and has positive parameters, then the derived $f(k) = F(K,L)/L$ function will satisfy the Inada conditions.

**Caveat** 
Based on the graphs they see, students of economics sometimes mistakenly assume that all strictly concave functions have these properties, but this is not the case. $f(k) = \sqrt{k} + k$ does not have the second one, while $f(k) = \sqrt{1+k}$ does not have the first one. Thus properties like $f$ being concave or non-linear are not sufficient, one has to assume the conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Because $\delta k$ is linear function, so the slope of the function is always constant, whereas $sf(k)$ is typically nonlinear function exponential function like $f(k)=k^\alpha$ with $0<\alpha<1$, so mathematically such function starts with steep slope, but this slope always gets smaller (this can be seen from $d/dk= \alpha k^{\alpha -1}$.

However, note depending on value of parameter $\delta$, $\delta k$ could have equal or  steeper slope but in such case capital accumulation is impossible because capital depreciates faster than it can be accumulated given $s$.

Comment: Can you please give me a depreciation parameter $\delta$ at which the slope of $\delta k$ will always be steeper than the slope of, let's say, $0.5\sqrt{k}$? If not, can you please explain what you mean by your second paragraph.

Comment: @Giskard $\delta$ that satisfies $\delta > \max \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$ for k>0. Also savings rate can be just zero and in that case it’s trivial

Comment: But you specify "always", when you write "always steeper slope", so I don't think a $\delta > \max_{k>0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$ exists? You are right about the edge case of $s = 0$, but that seems quite specific, not useful for the general case.

Comment: @Giskard I edited out the word always

Comment: Interesting choice; I am still not sure what you are trying to say with the paragraph though!

Comment: @1muflon1  Adding to Giskard's point, surely $\lim_{k \to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}=\infty$?

Comment: @AdamBailey yes what should I have said is always greater or equal than, hence my edit